# I have working code for email send but im not sure how to edit it

Tags: php, email

I'm not sure is it okay to ask this. But can some one help me just to edit this code so it redirects me to my home page. I know that i need to set header location just not sure exactly where cause im totally new to php. Here is the code.

```
<?php


$from = $_POST['Name'];
$sendTo = $_POST['Email'];
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name',  'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); // 
$okMessage = 'Contact form share button submited. Url of page will arrive in few seconds!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
$link = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];


try
{
    $emailText = "$link You got message from shared button.\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
?>
```

Comment: check for errors; it's the only way to tell and learn

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: I forgot to say that , that ive tried to set in header('Content-Type: application/json'); instead i wrote header("Location: http://mywebpage.com "); but it didnt worked so i asked .

Answer (score -1):

You could add

```
header("Location: page.php");
```

Just after

```
$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
```

Or after

```
echo $responseArray['message'];
```

Comment: Ive tried that allreardy didnt worked,  but thank you.

Comment: You could turn on errors and see what the problem is. It could be that headers are already being sent before you call the header location code. The other option would be to use a redirect in JavaScript. Either close your php tags and use JS or echo it in php

Comment: Yeah @user2977046, that is how you're meant to change the page.  You're evidently getting some other problem that is preventing you from setting the header.  This is called the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/270486).  It is possible that you already sent a response to the browser (could be text), which would invalidate new headers, is there any other code attached that might do this?